# Как убрать переносы строки из списка при обработке в python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

У меня есть csv-файл, который содержит строки с 2 значениями в каждой строке. Я работа в Python 3.7. Мне нужно получить информацию из второго значения и записать в эту же строку ответ.

Я решил прочитать документ построчно, заключить значения в список и работать со значениями этого списка. Для этого я сделал следующее:

```
with open('datafile.csv', "r") as file:
    for row in file:
        red_row = row.split(',')
        print(red_row)
```

Но в качестве ответа получил списки, у которых в последнем значении сохраняется перенос строки:

[193376,предположение\n]

Вопрос: как мне убрать перенос строки \n из второго значения и вставить в конец третьего? Можно ли это сделать стандартными библиотеками python3? Или может быть я выбрал не самый лучший путь для выполнения своей задачи и есть какой-то альтернативный путь, о котором я не знаю?

P.S. я только начинаю программировать и многие вещи еще не понимаю. Я был бы очень благодарен за подробное объяснение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пользовались модулем `csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `.strip()` перед `.split(',')`:

```
with open('datafile.csv') as file:           # "r" не нужно (но может быть) 
    for row in file:
        red_row = row.strip().split(',')
        print(red_row)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Метод `.strip()` убирает пустые символы (как например пробел, табулятор и `'\n'`) из начала и конца строки.

Существуют тоже методы `.lstrip()` (*«left strip»*) и `.rstrip()` (*«right strip»*) для удаления только из начала или из конца строки; в вашем случае `.rstrip()` тоже подходящий.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @MVA123123, не стоит. :-)